# React-select isMulti does not work in Version1

Tags: react-select

I had React-Select version1 and recently had to upgrade to v2 since v1 would not support isMulti. But it caused a lot of issues like style changes and requiring 'value' attribute in the options and stuff. Those were fixed but when I pushed my code to dev server, realized, dev server has a lower node version that is not compatible with react-select V2. I do not have an option to upgrade node version. What would be the best alternative to have multiselect and no upgrade to react-select 2

Comment: Do you have a special need to move from v1 to v2 ?

Comment: isMulti does not work in V1

Comment: I know but is the `multi` props from v1 not enough for your needs ?